# how to load pdf file in uiwebview from document directory in xcode?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, filepath, nsdocumentdirectory

i'm downloading my pdf file in document directory and then trying to show that pdf file

from that path to load in uiwebview but its not opening just a blank white page, i dont

understand why its not loading in uiwebview.

below is my code ,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 

NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathExtension:@".pdf"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];


NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

and my filepath is:

NSLog(@"Filepath------->> %@", filePath);

/Users/zee/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/BD79829B-95FF-4B91-94AD-830C6B1CD31D/Documents/myPDF.pdf

Please tell me why its not working and what should be the best solution

Thanks

Zeeshan Shaikh

Comment: Are you check pdf file in document directoy? that is good format and openable?

Comment: @karthika yes its openable.

Comment: ok fine. try with encoding the url.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 

NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sample.pdf"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];

NSString *encodedString=[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: thank yoou !, but i think from your code can be simplified, line 6, 7 and 8 no need.